# ASP classic: Object required: 'objContent.documentElement'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm working on a project that uses ASP classic. I'm having trouble with this error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: 'objContent.documentElement'
>
> /muhproject/includes/clsTransform.asp, line 138

How do I include `objContent.documentElement` into the project as the requirement needs?

File's line 138 is as follows:

```
'Attach fragment into pageContentXML
objContent.documentElement.appendChild xDoc2.documentElement
```

EDIT: Here's the full function of the code

```
'TransformContent - accepts content in XML data, and contentXSL file path
    public function TransformContent(scriptNameFull, fragmentXML)

        fragmentXML = decodeUTF8(fragmentXML)

        '1. Load the content.html (as XML)
        Dim objContent
        set objContent = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")  

        Dim contentXSLSpec
        contentXSLSpec = rootRel & "/muhproject/template/page/content.xsl"  'this is fixed

        objContent.async = false
        objContent.validateOnParse = false
        objContent.load( server.MapPath(scriptNameFull) )

        '2. Load fragmentXML XML fragment
        Dim xDoc2
        set xDoc2 = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
        xDoc2.Async = false
        xDoc2.resolveExternals = false
        xDoc2.validateOnParse = false
        xDoc2.loadXML(fragmentXML)


        '3. Attach fragment into pageContentXML
        objContent.documentElement.appendChild xDoc2.documentElement

        Dim objXSL
        set objXSL = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")

        objXSL.async = false
        objXSL.validateOnParse = false

        objXSL.load( server.mapPath(contentXSLSpec) )

        '3. Do the transformation

        Dim retVal
        retVal = objContent.transformNode(objXSL.documentElement)

        set objContent = nothing
        set xDoc2 = nothing
        set objXSL = nothing

        TransformContent = retVal

    end function
```

Comment: I think we need to see how you are creating that object `objContent` . Could you show some more code , /

Comment: Something wrong with your XMl, i guess; can you show the XML too ?

Comment: check the boolean return value to `xDoc2.loadXML(fragmentXML)` to see if the XML loaded without error and check `xDoc2.parseError` if it didn't

Comment: Also, if your `documentFragment` is actually a document fragment (eg it has no single root element), consider using the [`createDocumentFragment()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759155(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, if you put an `if` statement around your `objContent.load` statement, then you can handle the case when there is a problem loading the data.

Comment: Also, check this page out. It has some ideas for handling failure of file loading [link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx)

Comment: Could also be file permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

To drive oracle's argument home:

Stripped of all accidentials, your script is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objContent : Set objContent = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objContent.load "nosuch.xml"
objContent.documentElement.appendChild "pipapo"
```

output:

```
cscript 18732533.vbs
...\18732533.vbs(5, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'ocumentElement'
```

If you'd follow the rule "Make sure of your optimistic assumptions by checking for errors!", your script would look like:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objContent : Set objContent = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objContent.load "nosuch.xml"
If 0 = objContent.ParseError Then
   objContent.documentElement.appendChild "pipapo"
Else
   WScript.Echo objContent.ParseError.Reason
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 18732533.vbs
The system cannot locate the resource specified.
```

(resp. some info about not well-formed content of an existing file).